# php include or include_once function is not working

Tags: php, html

I have php code in parameter_file.php file as below. when i called this file in index.php file, its not reading any values ! Both the files are present under same directory and using latest php 5.4

**parameter_file.php**

```
<?php
$color='red';
$car='BMW';
?>
```

**Body of index.php**

```
<?php include 'parameter_file.php';
echo  "value is : ".$color;
?>
```

Could you please tell where/what the problem is ?

Comment: parameter_file.php and index.php in the same folder??

Comment: Try using require instead of include - it will be more verbose about errors. See if you get an error message when using require 'parameter_file.php';

Comment: Maybe parameter_file.php is'nt in the same folder than index.php in this case you will have to use something like this `include '../folderhere/parameter_file.php';` or something like it.

Comment: What is the path of `index.php` and `parameter_file.php`?

Comment: both the files are in same folder

Comment: which php version and OS are you using? php less then 4.3 and windows may not work

Comment: Maybe chmod does not allow the server to read the file? try chmod 777 to exclude this reason.

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_exists('parameter_file.php'));` output if you place it inside `index.php`? Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on?

Comment: Check for a typo in your file name, otherwise the code should work fine.

Comment: @h2ooooooo : error on helped me to find the issue...

Comment: @logan Then do the nice thing and tell everyone else what it was in case they come here looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error_reporting(E_ALL)` helped to find where the issue is...
the problem was both the files are present in same folder but under different sub domain. I have corrected it ., worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vars are *not always* transmitted between files, excepted if you declare it `global` before including the file

```
<?php
global $car, $color;
include 'parameter_file.php';
echo  "value is : ".$color;
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
include ('parameter_file.php');
```

it must be in brackets () - actually without brackets it's also possible, but it works differently and can depend on the server settings. Check the official doc for details.

And of course variables are transmitted between files, all the included files comprise the same namespace with the file where you include them.

global declaration is needed to access a global variables inside functions.

Comment: are you sure? All examples on php.net are without brackets. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: all my codes  have brackets and it's been working for me for 10+ years :)

Just try it and let me know. Your code seems to be OK.
I'd probably also move include to the new line from <?php, but it's just for the sake of accuracy.